# May an F-2 visa holder marry inside the US with a US citizen/green card holder without ending the previous marriage?

Tags: immigration, greencard, marriage, divorce

If someone with F-2 visa status comes to the US, then wants to marry with a US citizen/green card holder, should he/she ends/gets divorce of his/her previous wife/husband even if their marriage happened outside of the US and they both aren't US citizens/green card holders?

Answer (score 2):

> May an F-2 visa holder marry inside the US with a US citizen/green card holder without ending the previous marriage?

No.

> If someone with F-2 visa status comes to the US, then wants to marry with a US citizen/green card holder, should he/she ends/gets divorce of his/her previous wife/husband even if their marriage happened outside of the US and they both aren't US citizens/green card holders?

Yes. If you are married in one place, you are married everywhere (barring some edge cases like polygamous marriages). You can't just go to another country and consider yourself single. You need to divorce before you can marry again. If you are residing in the US, you may be able to do the divorce in the US.

Comment: I hope you don't mind my edit.